# How to Connect to localhost HBase with Java

Tags: java, connection, hbase

When I start HBase as embedded it works perfectly.

I am on Ubuntu 12.04, and I have installed hbase 0.90.5 by downloading tar.gz and decompressing on opt directory.

HBase is started correctly, in log there is no crash nor an exception so it seems that HBase is correctly installed. hbase-site.xml is as simple as:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
</property>
```

Then my etc/hosts file is even more simple:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

127.0.0.1 alex-desktop
```

Note that I have read about removing hostname from this file, but doing this only causes an error while starting hbase. So I decided to leave as shown here.

And finally my Java code:

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    config.clear();
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
    config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181");
    config.set("hbase.master", "localhost:60000");
```

I get exception in the log:

```
2/10/25 21:41:59 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x13a996f3e1d000b, negotiated timeout = 40000

12/10/25 21:41:59 INFO client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: getMaster attempt 0 of 1 failed; no more retrying.
java.io.IOException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:60001 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.wrapException(HBaseClient.java:954)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:923)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:150)
at $Proxy6.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:183)
```

Note that port 60001 changes, sometimes it is this port but can also be any other like 46666.

Also I have tried exporting export `HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true` but it doesn't help.
I don't know what can I do next, because I don't know what is this random port.

Anyone knows what is happening?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: you are using hbase in pseudo distributed or in the standalone mode?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using the `same` HBase version in your client code as you have in your cluster. Generally, in case of version mismatch `EOFException` will occur.